# Postfix + MySQL ENCRYPT() encryption method change

Tags: encryption, hash, databases, mysql

I already have my mail server (postfix, courier, mysql) and roundcube as my webmail client, Encrypt() is the current password encryption function,

Is there a way to change the default password encryption from Encrypt() function to md5 or any other encryption functions?

And if yes, is it possible to apply it automatically to all old existing users?

Comment: Why MD5 instead of SHA?

Comment: Actually didn't decide yet which function to switch too, don't even know if switching is possible, then i can decide anything else rather than Encrypt()

Comment: MD5 is a hashing function... if you need a hash just use MD5 function (or for more security SHA...)  I think the names of the functions will depend on the version of MySQL you are using.  When changing the hash function you will need to force all users to create new passwords (unless you stored those in plain text).    You'd need legacy functions until every user updated their passwords, methinks.

Comment: btw, if you are currently encrypting passwords instead of hashing them, that could be an issue in and of itself... is there any reason you need to decrypt?

Answer (score 0):

i having the same problems. In my case, still use ECRYPT as a method. So, to resolve changes in this way:

$config['password_query'] = 'UPDATE mail.users SET password=ENCRYPT(%p) WHERE email=%u LIMIT 1';

I apologize for the spelling, but I am Brazilian and I need to translate on google translator.